# Convergence of series of positive terms: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{(\log n)}^{p}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series, monotone-functions

I have applied Cauchy condensation test for to test the convergence the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{(\log n)}^{p}}$, where p is constant, I got $\frac{1}{{\log 2}^{p}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k}}{k^{p}}$ . I do not understand for which value of p such that  the original series is convergent. Also have used Cauchy integral test but did not solve the improper integral $\int_{2}^{\infty}
{\frac{1}{(\log{x})^{p}}}dx$. 
I do not understand the convergent or not, if it convergent what is the value of p will be.   Please some one help me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. Using the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), you are led to consider convergence/divergence of the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k}}{k^{p}}.
$$ But, for any fixed $p$, we have
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2^{k}}{k^{p}} \neq 0
$$ thus your inital series is **always divergent**.

Comment: Hi Olivier, I don't understand the last term, did you mean however "large" $p$ I take, we can always find a $k$ such that $2^k>k^p$?

Comment: For any fixed $p$, one has $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2^{k}}{k^{p}}=\infty\neq 0$ leading to the divergence of the given series.

Comment: Hi @s1mple, the OP series never converges, since for any fixed p, the general term does not tend to zero... Hope you are Ok with (say $p=2$)$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2^{k}}{k^2}=\infty.$$

Comment: Yes. I understand now. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The integral test should work too. Setting $logx=t$ gives $dx=e^tdt$ gives a new integral of the form $\frac{e^t}{t^n}$ integrating to infinity. I see an e-power in the numerator against a polynomial term in the denominator so I am getting "wet feet" here. Can you finish it?